# Retrieve .yaml data, using PHP

Tags: php, forms, parsing, content-management-system, yaml

I'm using a flat-file CMS to save simple, user submitted form posts to a folder.

They contain the username of the user that submitted the post. And the text that they submitted in the form:

[folders & files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMwe7.jpg)

(I've saved these submissions as .yaml, but another text format might be more efficient.)

---

My Aim, is to create a dashboard for the current user, that parses the text submissions, and displays them on the page. Resulting in something like this.

[Desired Page Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSO4I.jpg)

I want to retrieve the text data only if the current users username matches the username in the folder.

---

I'd appreciate any help, from if i'm thinking about the process in an effeciant way, to how I'd pull the .yaml data to the page.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't really get the obsession with yaml today. Why not just use json, which there is support for in PHP without adding extra libraries to your code? Yaml can be nice in some configs that should be simple and handled by non developers.

Comment: Still quite new and learning as I go - .json sounds like a wise move. I could do that. and process the form into variables to be recalled?

Comment: I've added an answer with example on how to save and then retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use JSON for this instead of yaml, since there already is support for JSON in PHP. Yaml makes more sense if you have configuration files that needs to be really readable and that users should edit manually.

**Write example:**

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/file', json_encode($_POST));
```

**Read example:**

```
$content = json_decode(file_get_contents('/path/to/file'), true);
```

The `$content` variable will now have the same content as your `$_POST` variable did.

The second argument, `true`,  in `json_decode()` makes sure that we get an associative array instead of an object.

Read more about [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Thanks guys, after looking into json that makes so much sense. I think I'm going to try making a form template that constructs .json variables. Then parse it to the page with php's json decoding as you've pointed out. If I can get the filename to use the username, then I should be able to call the filename as the current users username, am I on the right track? Is this efficient?